# How to compare key and value in more than two array?

Tags: php

I am comparing three arrays in nested foreach conditions. Following are the arrays

```
    Array
(
    [master/city] => City
    [master/national_holiday] => National Holiday
    [master/operator_comments] => Operator Comments
    [master/sensors] => Sensors
    [master/modbus] => Modbus
    [master/manufacturers] => Manufacturers
    [master/make_model] => Make Model
    [master/dispatch_vendors] => Dispatch Vendors
)      

    Array
(
    [1] => View
    [2] => Write
)

Array
    (
        [master/city] => 1
        [master/national_holiday] => 2
        [master/operator_comments] => 1
        [master/sensors] => 2
        [master/modbus] => 1
        [master/manufacturers] => 2
        [master/make_model] => 1
    )
```

Now the scenario is as follows:-

My first foreach iteartes first array

Then in the same foreach i m using second foreach which itrates second array
again in second foreach i m using third foreach to iterate third array

In third foreach , i m comparing key of first array with the key of second array and comparing value of second array  with  key of third array

If above condition is satisfied then in my dropdown the specific option will append **selected**  Like `<option value="1" selected="">View</option>`

I am using following code

```
<?php
                    $first_array =  first_array();
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($first_array as $k => $val) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                      <td class="mailbox-name">{{ $val }}</td>
                      <td><?php $second_array =  second_array(); ?>
                            <select class="form-control master-menu" name="master_menu[{{$k}}]">
                              <option value="">Select Role</option>
                                <?php

                                    foreach ($second_array as $key => $value) {
                                        foreach ($third_array as $mkey => $mval) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"
                                    <?php if (($mkey == $k) && ($mval == $key)) { echo "selected"; } ?>><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                                <?php } } ?>
                            </select>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++;  } ?>
```

I am using above code and getting issue that in second array there two values and in third array five values so in my dropdown count of option are ten insted of two.
This is my output. 
[image]

Please suggest me.

Comment: what is the difference with your previous question ?

Comment: @splash58 i was unable explain properly and did not get expected result form previous question hence i raised question again with proper explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this? I have simplified the process to demonstrate what is happening. I have also added the correct select values:

```
foreach ($first_array as $key => $value) {
?>

    <p><?php echo $value; ?></p>


    <?php foreach ($second_array as $second_key => $second_value) { ?>



        <?php if ($key == $second_key) { ?>
            <select>    

                <?php foreach ($third_array as $third_key => $third_value) { ?>

                    <option <?php echo ($third_key == $second_value ? 'selected=selected' : null); ?>><?php echo $third_value; ?></option>

                <?php } ?>



            </select>

        <?php } else { ?>

            <select>    

                <?php foreach ($third_array as $third_key => $third_value) { ?>

                    <option ><?php echo $third_value; ?></option>

                <?php } ?>



            </select>

        <?php } ?>


   <?php } ?>


<?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks @beingalex... finally my code working bcoz of u... :)

Comment: but if record is not found then dropdown is not showing because if condition is there any method to show second array..

Comment: yes if i put else condition then it added set of dropdowns can you provide else condition code please...

Answer (score 0):

For example you may try this code

```
foreach ($tmparray as $innerarray) {
    //check type
    if (is_array($innerarray)) {
        //echo through inner loop
        foreach ($innerarray as $value) {
            echo $value;
        }
    } else {
        //one,two,three
        echo $innerarray;
    }
}
```